# Why are DNS server addresses lost after reboot?

Tags: macos, dns

I applied OpenDNS server addresses to Network Preference > Advanced > DNS.

These were applied first under user account, then believing I needed to apply as Admin. Yet upon reboot they're replaced with 127.0.0.54

Why don't OpenDNS server addresses continue to apply after reboot?

Comment: Is the OpenDNS IP address the only entry under DNS Servers? It shouldn't be removing it. Try using Google's DNS and see what happens. (Set DND to 8.8.8.8, choose OK, hit Apply, quit System Preferences, restart, and check.)

Comment: Yes its the only addresses under DNS. Tried the google DNS 8.8.8.8 and got the same results,the applied address is replaced by 127.0.0.54 again after reboot

Comment: Do you have DNSCrypt (http://opendns.github.com/dnscrypt-osx-client/) installed? It is a software by OpenDNS that encrypts DNS traffic and it appears to use 127.0.0.54.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the answer in the comments attached to the question (which you have already stated is your solution), I can only offer to others that do not use DNSCrypt that find similarly described symptoms. What fixed the problem for me, which was exactly as you described: after adding DNS servers and closing and reopening System Preferences and the Advanced section of the Network Control Panel, the DNS server list would not retain its data, took me time and effort to discover. PEBKAC: I was closing System Preferences without clicking the Apply button, which you will only see once leaving the Advanced section of that Control Panel. Hope this helps!